# mysql query optimizer uses index with select id, but not with select *

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have the following query:

```
select * from `tracked_employments`
where `tracked_employments`.`file_id` = 10006000
and `tracked_employments`.`user_id` = 1003230
and `tracked_employments`.`can_be_sent` = 1
and `tracked_employments`.`type` = ‘jobchange’
and `tracked_employments`.`file_type` = ‘file’
order by `tracked_employments`.`id` asc
limit 1000
offset 2000;
```

and this index
[image]

explain tells me that it does not use the index, but when I replace * with id it does use it. Why does it make a difference what columns I select?

Comment: `id` is primary key or a part of it? if so then this value is stored in the index records and can be extracted from the index. The fact that `SELECT *` does not use index means that (1) there are columns other than used in this index or in primary key in the table structure, and (2) the query selects more than 5-7% of total table rows (by table statistic data). In such case the table scan is more fast.

Comment: I just don't understand why the selected columns should make any difference at all. I thought what would happen is that first it picks all matching rows and then just returns the selected columns. So for the matching part it would not even need to know what the select statement says

Comment: Test `SELECT id, another_column ..` where `another_column` is not present in both this and primary index expression - and server will use table scan.

Comment: As @Akina is stating - the database is going to use a variety of inputs when determining what plan is most efficient (has the lowest cost).  So to better understand why it is arriving at these decisions, please gather and update your answer with the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` output for both queries of interest.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE tracked_employments` so we can see the details of the indexes.  And also the datatypes, which could be part of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Both you and Akina have misconceptions about how InnoDB indexing works.

Let me explain the two ways that *that* query may be executed.

Case 1.  Index is used.

This assumes the datatypes, etc, all match the 5-column composite index that seems to exist on the table.  Note: because all the tests are for `=`, the order of the columns in the `WHERE` clause and the `INDEX` does not matter.

In InnoDB, `id` (or whatever column(s) are in the `PRIMARY KEY` are implicitly added onto the index.

The lookup will go directly (in the Index's BTree) to the first row that matches all 5 tests.  From there, it will scan forward.  Each 'row' in the index has the PK, so it can reach over into the data's BTree to find any other columns needed for `*` (cf `SELECT *`).

But, it must skip over 2000 rows before delivering the 1000 that are desired.  This is done by actually stepping over each one, one at a time.  That is, `OFFSET` is not necessarily fast.

Case 2.  Don't bother with the index.

This happens based on some nebulous analysis of the 3000 rows that need to be touched and the size of the table.

The rationale behind possibly scanning the table without using the index is that the bouncing between the index BTree and the data BTree may be more costly than simply scanning the data BTree.  Note that the data BTree is already in the desired order -- namely by `id`.  (Assuming that is the PK.)  That avoids a sort of up to 1000 rows.

Also, certain datatype issues *may* prevent the use of the index.

I do need to ask what the client will do with 1000 rows all at once.  If it is a web page, that seems awfully big.

Case 3 -- Just `SELECT id`

In this case, all the info is available in the index, so there is no need to reach into the data's BTree.